# How much did brigs of 200 tons vary in 1800?

Tags: architecture, age-of-sail

I am researching the LYDIA, a brig of 200 tons, built of teak around 1800. I think it had a crew of around 20. (Details on the ship are in Judge Howay's "List of trading vessels in the maritime fur trade").

Not having found any drawing or diagram of it yet, I'm wondering whether  another similarly-sized brig of the same era would have been substantially the same. To what degree would they have looked alike? Could LYDIA have had any unusual features or would it have been built to a well-known pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that the description - "a brig of 200 tons" - really tells you is that the vessel was brig-rigged, that is it had 2 masts (fore and main), and it had an approximate hull volume [calculated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder%27s_Old_Measurement#History_and_derivation) at 200 tons (not to be confused with displacement). Some sources make the distinction between a [brig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brig) and a [brigantine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigantine), while others might not.

The hull form could vary depending on the ship's intended use and the time period in which it was built. Teak was a common contruction material for vessels in Asia, where it was more plentiful than the oak that was the preferred material in Europe.

Comment: I see that the ship's tonnage and the material don't explain the whole plan. While I know this ship had a few guns, I don't know what its builders had in mind for it.